# how does nextLine discard the input?

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

I'm a beginner at java. I wanted to know how the `nextLine()` Method discards your current input?  For example assume the following code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
```

After the `input.nextLine()` is executed, the value in "input" is discarded. I wanted to know how does it work?

Comment: you discard it when you ignore the result returned by `nextLine()`

Answer (score 3):

when you enter number and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, It reads integer value to `a` and  keeps `\n` in buffer

Now when you invoke `nextLine()` it directly gets newline character from buffer skipping user's input

to avoid it put `next()` method call to read left over `\n` from buffer before invoking `newLine()`and after successful execution of `nextInt()`

Comment: Thanks dear Joshi, but unfortunately I couldn't get what you mean...
Can you give me the name of a book to read more or a good resource...?

Answer (score 1):

input is an object representing a scanner. When nextLine is executed, the function reads until a newline character is encountered, deposits that data into a buffer and returns the buffer. The important point to note is that "input" doesn't store any data. It stores a representation of a file and a position within that file from which you are reading. Therefore nothing in input is discarded. Rather you are simply not using the value returned by nextLine, but the side effect of the nextLine function still increments the input object's location within the file.